# How to use PodioItem::filter()

Tags: php, api, podio

I'm with a doubt in `PodioItem::filter()` method . How do I filter by example only items in the `Manager` field which is equal to `Airton` ?

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried

Comment: I tried nothing.
Why, in the official documentation of Podio , you do not see the option to filter by a specific field

Answer (score 0):

```
$attributes = array(
                'filters'=>array($manger_field_id=>'Airton')      
              );   

$filtered_values=PodioItem::filter( $app_id, $attributes, $options);
```

Here `$manger_field_id` is the id of the manager field. And please note that if the manager field is a reference field,then you should provide the item id in the value part.